# How far does bookcase have to be next to baseboard heater?

Tags: safety, heater

How far does furniture have to be from the side of a baseboard heater? My bookcase will be 2 inches from the side of the baseboard heater, I would like it to be closer so I can use the outlet on the other side of the bookcase but will settle for 2 inches if I have to. Is that safe? I can only find information on how far curtains have to be away or something in front of heater but not from side. Thanks!

Comment: What make/model is the baseboard heater in question?

Comment: Not sure, it came with the place. Very standard Canadian baseboard heater under living room window. It looks like this. http://www.stelpro.com/en-CA/electric-baseboard

Comment: I would not want the book case in contact with the baseboard heater but mouldings usually do come in close contact if not touching and the baseboard is screwed to the wall, some walls are wood paneling, some sheetrock so I don't see a problem with the bookshelves being next to the baseboard heaters.

Comment: Good point about the moulding, I didn't think of that. Thank you.

Comment: The heater should be designed for zero clearance for safety. It should be impossible to ignite wood or paper even if it is direct contact. However, it needs to have some clearance to allow airflow for it to work efficiently. Also, the warmth can have a drying effect on the wood of the bookcase and possibly shorten its life. 2" clearance should be plenty to allow airflow and a good safety factor.